# Lua String Split

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Hi I've got this function in JavaScript:

```
    function blur(data) {
    var trimdata = trim(data);
    var dataSplit = trimdata.split(" ");
    var lastWord = dataSplit.pop();
    var toBlur = dataSplit.join(" ");
 }
```

What this does is it take's a string such as "Hello my name is bob" and will return 
toBlur = "Hello my name is" and lastWord = "bob"

Is there a way i can re-write this in Lua?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Lua's pattern matching facilities:

```
function blur(data) do
    return string.match(data, "^(.*)[ ][^ ]*$")
end
```

How does the pattern work?

```
^      # start matching at the beginning of the string
(      # open a capturing group ... what is matched inside will be returned
  .*   # as many arbitrary characters as possible
)      # end of capturing group
[ ]    # a single literal space (you could omit the square brackets, but I think
       # they increase readability
[^ ]   # match anything BUT literal spaces... as many as possible
$      # marks the end of the input string
```

So `[ ][^ ]*$` has to match the last word and the preceding space. Therefore, `(.*)` will return everything in front of it.

For a more direct translation of your JavaScript, first note that there is no `split` function in Lua. There is `table.concat` though, which works like `join`. Since you have to do the splitting manually, you'll probably use a pattern again:

```
function blur(data) do
    local words = {}
    for m in string.gmatch("[^ ]+") do
        words[#words+1] = m
    end
    words[#words] = nil     -- pops the last word
    return table.concat(words, " ")
end
```

`gmatch` does not give you a table right away, but an iterator over all matches instead. So you add them to your own temporary table, and call `concat` on that. `words[#words+1] = ...` is a Lua idiom to append an element to the end of an array.

Comment: Thanks for the response, using the first bit of code `return string.match(data, "^(.*)[ ][^ ]*$")` i am able to return the first bit of the string, how would I do a separate sting match to just return the last word?

Comment: You can actually do both in one call: `return string.match(data, "^(.*)[ ]([^ ]*)$")` will have two return values (one for each capturing group). If you need it in a separate call, simply use one capturing group at a time.

Comment: I was thinking of returning two separate values to two different vars `local hiddentxt = string.match(dataTable.lines[i].text, "^(.*)[ ][^ ]*$")` so in this example it will return "Hello my name is" and i wanted another `local showntxt = ..` which would return "bob" as i need to treat the values in the different vars slightly differently

Comment: Ah i think i know what you mean do something like this `local hiddentxt, showntxt = string.match(dataTable.lines[i].text, "^(.*)[ ]([^ ]*)$")` return both values

Comment: @Tam2 To be picky, I don't think this will trim the string first. To incorporate that something like `^[ ]*(.*)[ ]([^ ]*)[ ]*$` might be used. That should make sure the spaces are matched *outside* of the capturing groups so they don't become part of the result. (I could be wrong though since I haven't actually used any of this much yet, and just started using Lua last week.)

Comment: @Supr Thanks, i've only just started using Lua too

Comment: @Tam2 yes I meant something like `local hiddentxt, showntxt = ...`. @Supr, yes, trimming would have to be taken care of separately. Also note, that my first approach will choke on the edge case of only a single word in the string. This version should take that into account: `"^(.-)[ ]?([^ ]*)$"` (and again, if trimming is relevant, add `[ ]*` as in Supr's comment).

Comment: @m.buettner I don't think its trimming the text, i've got `local hiddentxt, showntxt = string.match(event.target.text, "^[ ]*(.-)[ ]?([^ ]*)$")` and if i enter "Hello, my name is bob!      " it will capture the entire string in 'hiddentxt'

Comment: @Tam2 that's because you only added the trimming part at the beginning, but added the space at the end. try `"^[ ]*(.-)[ ]?([^ ]*)[ ]*$"`